# Understanding an Android TV box inside

Tags: android-tv, android-hardware, tvbox

I bought an android TV box . it was not working .When i first contacted the seller (Chinese) they send me a software and ask me to connect the android box to PC with USB to USB cable. But unfortunately my pc was showing , more power needed (than USB provides) to connect. So the seller asked me to open the box and pull out white thing in the img attached. I don't have a clue what I am going to do.Before i do that i would like to know whats that white part and whats the use of it , how if its removed going to help me
[image]

Comment: That's a heatsink: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_sink

Comment: Ok thanks..Any idea how will that help me , or do u think they are now helping me to connect the box to pc (which was previously showing need more power) ?..

Comment: I don't see how removing that heatsink would solve your problem, the seller must have misunderstood your question. I'm afraid I can't really help you other than asking, does that Android box need an AC adapter? If so, did you plug it in when you tried to connect it to your PC via USB?

Comment: Thanks a lot answering